# When and why we should to use class System.ComponentModel.Container?

Tags: c#, system.componentmodel

Is anybody could explain when and why we should use `System.ComponentModel.Container`, please? Recently I have met using of this class [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120320065247/http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/article.php/c6919__2/Using-Timers-in-a-Windows-Service.htm), but really cannot understand what a benefit can get us this class there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, `System.ComponentModel` namespace exists for supporting component development - components can be visual (controls) and non-visuals. IMO, one should develop Components (in this context `IComponent` implementations) when design time support is needed. For example, you can drag Components on to the design surface in Visual Studio and access their properties. In this context, `IContainer` & `Container` represent a holder that will contain one or more components. I seriously doubt if you need to use `System.ComponentModel.Container` directly - this class would be used by .NET framework and Visual Studio (or other designer tools) internally. As far as, the code that you have sighted, it appears to be quite outdated and for that matter, it is not even instantiating Component class (just a reference is created).