# COM objects in VS 2012 to use with VBSCRIPT

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, com, vbscript

Since the main application is in vbscript and it's uncomfortable to work with to do some things, I have to make something to be called from that app, so I've been asked to develop a dll to be used in an old vbscript IDE application.

I'm new to this kind of development... But I think I should create a COM Object. The thing is that not only I've never created a COM Object, but also... even when I've found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w29wacsy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) without much digging, it doesn't speak much of how to create them in VS2012 (My only IDE)

The question(s) is(are):

- Is COM object the solution I'm looking for? (*maybe it's something else, what you do to develop an object to be used in vbscript*)
- Is `System.ComponentModel.Component` and `COM Object` the same?
- How do I do it in VS2012?
- Which are the steps I have to make (*besides those you do when creating a simple console app*) that I should remember to do to make it work properly?

TIA!

Comment: Yes, COM is the best choice to allow a COM aware Windows Scripting Languages like VBS to interoperate with code in another language. See [How do I Create an ActiveX (COM) in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360160/how-do-i-create-an-activex-com-in-c)

Comment: But I can't seem to find `System.Runtime.InteropServices` in vs2012

Comment: Create a new c#(?) class library project & just add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Comment: I can create a `Component` from `System.ComponentModel` and when I dig a bit into the packaged class, it uses `System.Runtime.InteropServices`... I don't have to add any reference... Ok, I'll try the steps on your link!

Comment: Do you know of any usage example on the web of `System.ComponentModel.Component`?

Comment: Why do you want to use it? To create a COM object follow the instructions in the linked post, no direct use of System.ComponentModel.Component is required in that simple case.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was the vs2012 way of doing COMs... but I saw this (http://stackoverflow.com/q/4667057/684646) so I'll do what you said, and close this if it works

Comment: Ow so... it doesn't work... but I think it's not working because of what references it has internally. This is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/q/17472913/684646 Should I close this one?